# There's the word undefined at the top of my file produced by fs.writeFileSync

Tags: node.js, file, fs

I want to grab all the Markdown files that starts with the word `scene` (e.g. `scene-01.md`), combine them, then join their content into a file.

This is the code:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as path from 'path'

const dirname = path.join(__dirname, '../')
const filenameStart = 'scene'
const resultFileName = 'result.md'

var filenames = fs.readdirSync(dirname).filter(file => file.startsWith(filenameStart))

let result: string
filenames.forEach(filename => {
    console.log(filename)
    const content = fs.readFileSync(dirname + filename, 'utf-8')
    result += content
})

console.log('finished')

fs.writeFileSync(resultFileName, result)
```

The code works but there's the word `undefined` at the very top of the generated file (`result.md`):

```
undefined<!--
Scene: 1
-->
```

I thought `writeFileSync` had tried to write content before `readFileSync` was done. So I added some console logs. But the order seems correct:

```
scene-01.md
scene-02.md
scene-03.md
scene-04.md
finished
```

What could be the problem? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The result is undefined, set it to empty string.

```
let result = ''
```

Try this.

Comment: Oh, `undefined` is gone. Why is that?

Comment: default value for a variable is undefined, as you are using it to append with content, it is appending string "undefined", welcome to JavaScript